# "ng2-CKEditor" node module is not working with typescript[Angular2]

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ckeditor, mean-stack

I am trying to configure CKEditor in my angular2 application.
I am using node as my backend platform and i am using ng2-CKEditor npm module.

Below are my code in respective files.

**index.html::**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="app/images/myblog.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/app.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**systemjs.config.ts::**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'ng2-ckeditor': 'app/utils/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './js/main',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**main.ts::**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CKEditorModule} from 'ng2-ckeditor';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppModule]
})
export class AppMain { }

platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.component.ts::**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  //templateUrl: 'app/templates/write-blog.html'
  template: `
    <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="content" debounce="500">
      <p>Hello <strong>world</strong></p>
    </ckeditor>
    <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
   constructor(){
      //this.content = '<p>Hello <strong>World !</strong></p>'
      }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CKEditorModule} from 'ng2-CKEditor'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, CKEditorModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Error::**

> zone.js:344 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ckeditor'. ("
>       ][(ngModel)]="content" debounce="500">
>
> Hello **world**
>
> "): AppComponent@1:14
>   'ckeditor' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ckeditor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ckeditor' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>       [ERROR ->]
>
> Hello **world**
>
> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ckeditor'. ("
>       ][(ngModel)]="content" debounce="500">
>
> Hello **world**
>
> "): AppComponent@1:14
>   'ckeditor' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ckeditor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ckeditor' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>       [ERROR ->]
>
> Hello **world**
>
> http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8530:21)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16905:53)
>       at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:85)
>       at Set.forEach (native)
>       at compile (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:49)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:85:43)
>       at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:451:57
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:37)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:47)consoleError @ zone.js:344_loop_1 @ zone.js:371drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:375ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:297
>   zone.js:346 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:346_loop_1 @ zone.js:371drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:375ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:297

As i am new to angular2 with typescript and basically for MEAN stack, please help.
I check other post for the same issue but did not help to resolve my issue.

Comment: but it is properly visible.. is n't it? Anyway editing it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `FormsModule` to your module's `imports` in order to use `ngModel` directive because it is part of `FormsModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CKEditorModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
```

Your code is also very messy, you should check out official [Angular 2 quickstart app](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to see how your code should be structured.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I have added CKEditorModule to my module's import. Now it shows  **http://localhost:3000/ng2-CKEditor  not found**

Comment: @Jyotirmay I don't know how your project looks like, but problem is probably in `systemjs.config.js`, you should check if this path is correct: `'ng2-ckeditor': 'app/utils/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The issue was with both non-inclusion of CKEditor and formsModule in module's import and wrong path in systemjs.config.js.   However, is it enough to include formsModule and CKEditorModule in module's imports or do i have to include it in component and main.ts as well. Currently i have included them everywhere. It is a total new stuff for me. So just experimenting around.

Comment: @Jyotirmay It is enough to include them in module's imports. I can see you're a little bit lost, you should read official Angular's docs about modules, everything's explained really well and it has great examples: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Sure. I actually start implementing by reading from angular.io only, but my special needs pull me out of that and then i just lost.